# I am planning to create the api for signing up the user

Tags: file

Whenever the user registers with signup link, along with the data I want to send the default user image to the api. But I want to do this without clicking choose file button, I want the file to be sent in background

Note: Default image file is present in project directory

this.authHttpService.signup({...this.signupForm.value, file????});

how to send the actual image file present in the project directory?

Comment: Question is unclear + please provide more details (e.g. which language and framework do you use) and provide code you've done for signing up and which describes user model etc.

Comment: angular for front end and node.js for backend